# How to print Rails Multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I am trying to print a value from an external source is like this

```
:Email=>[{:Type=>"Primary", :Value=>"myemail@email.com"}]
```

When I am using :

```
@user_profile.userprofile[:Email]
```

I am getting this value

```
[{:Type=>"Primary", :Value=>"mymail@email.com"}]
```

How can I get this value I have tried few things but no success yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case 
`@user_profile.userprofile[:Email][0][:Type]` should return your value.
Because `email = [{:type=>"Primary", :value=>"myemail@email.com"}]` is array contains [0] element Hash.

Note: Don't use capitalized key in hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user_profile.userprofile[:Email][0][:Value]
```

Comment: Will you please explain this stuff [0]

Comment: @user2480754 @user_profile.userprofile[:Email] returns a array with one object in it. Since we want the first index of that array. We get it by using [0] where 0 is the number of the index. Index always starts counting at 0, then 1,2,3 etc.